# Mean and Covariance of folder of images in VB6

Tags: image, vb6

I have spent a lot of time downloading and trying to use various VB6 examples
to obtain the mean and covariance of YCbCr of jpg image files folder c:\test, however, I only get this code in Csharp only. How I can get it work in VB 6.0?

```
int num_samples = 0;
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(txtTrainingFolder.Text, "*.jpg"))
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(f))
        Add(bmp);
    num_samples++;
}
```

```
public void Add(Bitmap bmp)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            // Skip black pixels in training images
            if (c.R < 10 && c.G < 10 && c.B < 10)
                continue;
            double cb, cr;
            CbCr(c.R, c.G, c.B, out cb, out cr);
            sum_cr += cr;
            sum_cb += cb;
            sum_rr += cr * cr;
            sum_rb += cr * cb;
            sum_bb += cb * cb;
            n++;
        }
}

public void Finish()
{
    // Mean
    mean_cr = sum_cr / n;
    mean_cb = sum_cb / n;
    // Covariance
    cov00 = sum_bb / n - mean_cb * mean_cb;
    cov01 = sum_rb / n - mean_cr * mean_cb;
    cov11 = sum_rr / n - mean_cr * mean_cr;
    // Inverse covariance
    double det = cov00 * cov11 - cov01 * cov01;
    inv00 = cov00 / det;
    inv01 = -cov01 / det;
    inv11 = cov11 / det;
}

static void CbCr(byte r, byte g, byte b, out double cb, out double cr)
{
    double d0 = r / 255.0, d1 = g / 255.0, d2 = b / 255.0;
    cb = (-(0.148 * r) - (0.291 * g) + (0.439 * b) + 128);
    cr = ((0.439 * r) - (0.368 * g) - (0.071 * b) + 128);
    //cb = -37.797 * d0 - 74.203 * d1 + 112 * d2 + 128;
    //cr = 112 * d0 - 93.786 * d1 - 18.214 * d2 + 128;
}
```

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could compile the C# as a DLL class library, make it COM exposed [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx), and then call instances of your class in your VB6 code?

Comment: @Hrqls , thanks for your comments, How can I make the VB6 reads the images folder and reads evey JPG pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the project below:

when you click on the `picturebox` it then finds all jpg files in a directory and process them

```
'1 form with
'  1 picturebox: name=Picture1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Picture1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_Click()
    ProcessFiles "c:\temp\", "*.jpg"
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFiles(strPath As String, strMask As String)
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Dir$(strPath & strMask)
    Do Until Len(strFile) = 0
        'ShowFile strPath & strFile
        LoadFile strPath & strFile
        strFile = Dir$() 'find next file
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ShowFile(strFile As String)
    Caption = strFile
    Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFile(strFile As String)
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim bytArray() As Byte
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Binary As #intFile
        bytArray = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
    Close #intFile
End Sub
```

- `ShowFile` will show the file in the `picturebox`
- `LoadFile` will load the file into an array of bytes

Comment: That's grate the code works like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several online code C# to VB converters available. However, you will still need to do the VB.NET to VB6 conversion manually. The .NET and VB6 libraries are completely different and there are also many differences in the language features (e.g. the `Using` statement used in your code does not exist in VB6. It unloads the bitmap).

Converters:

- [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)
- [DOTNET Spider](http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/Csharp-To-Vb.aspx)
- [SharpDevelop code converter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx)
- [Telerik code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)